# How do I do string replace in JavaScript to convert ‘9.61’ to ‘9:61’?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the code line

```
var value = $("#text").val();
```

and `value = 9.61`, I need to convert `9.61` to `9:61`. How can I use the JavaScript replace function here?

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with jQuery, but just with plain old javascript.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I have a 'var' variable in javascript and I want to replace the string/characters in it. I tried this code: var myObject="my%dynamic%value\n"; myObject=myObject.replace("%","").replace("\n",""); Also tried myObject=myObject.replace('%','').replace('\n',''); It gives me the error that replace is not a known function

Comment: The exact error message for the above issue is  "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'replace'"

Answer (score 538, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
var value = $("#text").val(); // value = 9.61 use $("#text").text() if you are not on select box...
value = value.replace(".", ":"); // value = 9:61
// can then use it as
$("#anothertext").val(value);
```

---

Updated to reflect to current version of jQuery. And also there are a lot of answers here that would best fit to any same situation as this. You, as a developer, need to know which is which.

### Replace all occurrences

To replace multiple characters at a time use some thing like this: `name.replace(/&/g, "-")`. Here I am replacing all `&` chars with `-`. `g` means "global"

**Note** - you may need to add square brackets to avoid an error - `title.replace(/[+]/g, " ")`

> credits vissu and Dante Cullari

Comment: I tried that but an error occure as value.replace is not a function
:(

Comment: thephpdeveloper added something to make it correct... that should do it... see above edited

Comment: Is it possible to replace the last occurrence of this sub string with the other string

Comment: This won't work if we try to replace more than one value at a time. :(

Comment: To replace multiple characters at a time use some thing like this: `name.replace(/&/g, "-")`.  Here I am replacing all '&' chars with '-'. "g" means "global".

Comment: Note - you may need to add square brackets to avoid an error - `title.replace(/[+]/g, " ")`

Answer (score 67):

Probably the most elegant way of doing this is to do it in one step. See [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

```
$("#text").val(function(i, val) {
  return val.replace('.', ':');
});
```

compared to:

```
var val = $("#text").val();
$("#text").val(val.replace('.', ':'));
```

From the docs:

> ```
> .val( function(index, value) )
> ```
>
> function(index, value)A function
>   returning the value to set.
>
> This method is typically used to set
>   the values of form fields. For
>   `<select multiple="multiple">`
>   elements, multiple s can be
>   selected by passing in an array.
>
> The `.val()` method allows us to set
>   the value by passing in a function. As
>   of jQuery 1.4, the function is passed
>   two arguments, the current element's
>   index and its current value:
>
> ```
> $('input:text.items').val(function(index, value) {
>   return value + ' ' + this.className;
> });
> ```
>
> This example appends the string "
>   items" to the text inputs' values.

This requires jQuery 1.4+.

Comment: but as i see it the guy just want to change the `var value` and not the value in the text box as you suggested...

Answer (score 41):

I love [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)'s method chaining. Simply do...

```
    var value = $("#text").val().replace('.',':');

    //Or if you want to return the value:
    return $("#text").val().replace('.',':');
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with jquery chaining actually. After you've called `.val()` it's a regular string.

Answer (score 19):

A simple one liner:

```
$("#text").val( $("#text").val().replace(".", ":") );
```

Comment: this will only work if the value is a string... 
and also, calling `$("#text")` twice in there is not a good practice...

Comment: the OP also didn't specify that he wanted to replace the value of the `$("#text")` :)

Comment: Comment 1...Wrong. Comment 2...think about the logic of his question, no need to specify.

Comment: prove it.. and do remember, dated `Jan 27 '10 at 10:16`

Comment: you don't even know good practice.. you might want to read this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230727/jquery-optimization-best-practices

Comment: Why would you add an extra step by creating a variable first? Your link referred to using $this multiple times...I'm not seeing how this is "bad practice"...Remember the date? Um, ok...you answered the question over a year before I was even a member, I'm happy for you.

Comment: I'm not sure why you wanted to argue... `.val()` before doesn't return a string... I'm not sure if you were reading the comments... and history of edits...

Comment: I don't want to argue anything, I am here to learn man. But false teaching doesn't teach.  Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/dH6J3/ as you can see `.val()` DOES return a string, even when the original value is a number.

Comment: I'll give you that `.replace()` doesn't affect numbers, but `.val()` returns a string, hence why my answer works. No need to hack it with `$("#text").val()+""`

Comment: 2010... `.val()` before doesn't return a string.

Comment: Ohhh...I see what you are saying, it didn't then, but does now?

Comment: BUt if you knew that already, you wouldn't have said `this will only work if the value is a string` in your first comment ;) guess we  both learned something today...

Comment: here's one on the same year... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391274/jquery-replace-text-in-val

yes, current version don't have that error... but I don't really do it like that... cletus' answer is the best one

Comment: Makes sense, I wasn't aware of the complications back then, I have only been working with Jquery for about a year...thanks for the clearing it up!

Answer (score 6):

It can be done with the regular JavaScript function `replace()`.

```
value.replace(".", ":");
```

Comment: Im not sure if I missed something but since the value comes from the textbox it is a string no? Example http://jsfiddle.net/xMBuA/

Answer (score 4):

You can use JavaScript functions like replace, and you can wrap the jQuery code in brackets:

```
var value = ($("#text").val()).replace(".", ":");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#text").val(function(i,v) { 
   return v.replace(".", ":"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(9.61 + "").replace('.',':')
```

Or if your `9.61` is already a string:

```
"9.61".replace('.',':')
```