# Jquery - replace text in Val()

Tags: jquery, replace

I'm trying to replace parts of a Val() in jquery with some text but am not sure how to do this. `$(this).val()` returns "# number of...." - I would like to replace `#` with custom text, but Val doesn't seem to have a `replace()` function. I'm quite new to JQuery, so I might be missing something obvious.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can pass [a function to `.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) in 1.4+ like this:

```
$("#mySelector").val(function(i, v) { //index, current value
  return v.replace("#","Custom Text");
});
```

Comment: Perfect solution, Thank you +1

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget to add a .val() at the end :

```
$("#mySelector").val(function(i, v) {return v.replace("#","Custom Text");}).val();
```