# IE jquery takes two clicks to work

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am trying to setup a checkbox that checks all the child checkboxes, like a tree view.  The following codes works great in Firefox and Chrome but in IE, it takes two clicks to get it to work.  What am I missing?

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="org" value="orgs" id="orgs" />
<label for="All">Organizations</label>

<ul id="orglist">
    <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="org" value="1" id="1" />
            <label for="1">Org 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="org" value="1" id="2" />
            <label for="2">Org 2</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript/Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#orgs").change(function () {

        if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
            $("#navform #orglist :checkbox").attr("checked", true);
        }
        else {
            $("#navform #orglist :checkbox").attr("checked", false);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This isn't something with the IE "click to activate" "security option" MS added, is it?

Comment: Which version of IE is this affecting? works in IE8 here: http://jsfiddle.net/BX22n/

Comment: @Nick: probably 7 or below.  IE8 fixed some issues with checkbox state.

Comment: Not related but I think $(this).attr("checked") can be changed to just this.checked using DOM directly without jQuery selecting again.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was I was just using `checked` and not `checked="checked"`. Dumb mistake, but hopefully that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the state of a checkbox is in doubt for IE.  Try setting the checked property to false or whatever on initial page load.  For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="or" value="1" id="1" checked="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for an attribute, let jQuery do more work:

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("#navform #orglist :checkbox").attr("checked", "checked");
}
else {
    $("#navform #orglist :checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
}
```

Comment: Actually this should be `$("#navform #orglist :checkbox").attr("checked", this.checked);` if anything (or a `.each()`), don't let jQuery do "more work" use the faster DOM properties if available, generally speaking `$(this).is(":checked")` is extremely wasteful.  [There are other cases this applies as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230727/jquery-optimization-best-practices/3230788#3230788)

Comment: I'm still learning about jQuery optimization. What aspect is wasteful here? Is it in terms of milliseconds to perform the action and/or is it in terms of memory or computations necessary? Can you point me to some actual measurements?