# Jquery Find Replace

Tags: jquery

I have following HTML code

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="javascript:OpenNewWindow('/help_email.asp?ProductCode=122030', 350, 250);" class="pricecolor colors_productprice"><b><span class="PageText_L657n"><br><input type="Button" font face="arial" size="2" color="#ffbb00" value="submit best offer"> </Button>
```

What i want to do is FIND ALL occurrences of help_email.asp and replace it with help_email.php.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145988/jquery-string-replace

Comment: help_email.asp doesn't appear anywhere in the code you posted?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
$('body').html($('body').html().replace('help_email.asp','help_email.php'));
```

Comment: This way if there are any events associated to elements existing on the page before this code runs, or properties (not attributes, as in, stuff added using `prop()` not `attr()`) will be lost because they are not written in the HTML itself

Comment: yeah, the question wasn't to specific just want to provide an alternative in case the string was somewhere else than an anchor or link.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$(function() {
    var anchors = $("a[href*='help_email.asp'], a[onclick*='help_email.asp']");

    anchors.each(function() {
        var anchor = $(this);

        var originalHref = anchor.attr("href");
        anchor.attr("href", originalHref.replace(".asp", ".php") );

        var originalClick = anchor.attr("onclick");
        anchor.attr("onclick", originalClick.replace(".asp", ".php") ); 
    });
});
```

Note that `replace` is a standard JS function, not jQuery specific.

**References:**

- [jQuery Selectors API: Attribute Contains Selector [name*="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)
- [jQuery Selectors API: Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 'help_email.asp' appears only in the `href` attributes of anchor tags...

```
$('a').each(function () {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    href = href.replace('help_email.asp', 'help_email.php');
    $(this).attr('href', href);
})
```

but, why not just do this server-side, so the correct urls are already embedded in the page?