# remove all instances of a character in a string with something else javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I need to replace all `<br />` with a space. The below is the string that gets spitted out dynamically and i need to hide the br tags...

```
M,W,Th,F 7:30 AM - 4:00 PM<br />Tu 7:30 AM - 6:00 PM<br />
```

What am i doing wrong?is it possible to replace all other br tags with a comma except the last one, which will be repalced by a space

```
$('.WorkingHours').text().replace(/<br />/g, " ");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145988/jquery-string-replace

Answer is here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three issues with your code:

1. `$('.WorkingHours').text()` won't contain any HTML (so no `br` tags either), it only returns the text content of elements.
   `$('.WorkingHours').text()` returns:

   > `M,W,Th,F 7:30 AM - 4:00 PMTu 7:30 AM - 6:00 PM`

   whereas `$('.WorkingHours').html()` returns:

   > `M,W,Th,F 7:30 AM - 4:00 PM<br>Tu 7:30 AM - 6:00 PM<br>`
2. You have to escape the inner backslash in your expression. **Edit:** Having a look at the output of `.html()` it actually does not contain `<br />` but `<br>`. This might depend on the doctype of the document ([not working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ufJaH/2/), [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ufJaH/3/)).
3. You have to assign the value back to the element.

You might be able to do

```
$('.WorkingHours').html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/g, " "); 
});
```

but it would be much cleaner to not use regular expressions at all:

```
$('.WorkingHours').find('br').replaceWith(' ');
```

This finds all `br` element nodes and replaces them with a text node containing only a space.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/74SMe/)

**Update** (in response to one of your comments):  If you want to replace the last `br` with a full stop, you can use `.last()`:

```
$('.WorkingHours')
 .find('br').last().replaceWith('.')
 .end().replaceWith(' ');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ufJaH/4/)

Comment: Shouldn't $('.WorkingHours').find('br').remove() be more appropriate?

Comment: @SKS: I wanted to suggest that, but it won't add a space.

Comment: @FelixKling true. missed that space.. my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Couple things:

use `html()` to get the HTML of the node:

```
var rawHTML = $('.WorkingHours').html();
```

Use `\` to escape the `/` within your regex:

```
/<br \/>/g
```

Set the HTML to the return value of the replace function:

```
$('.WorkingHours').html(rawHTML.replace(/<br \/>/g, ' ');
```

#### End Product:

```
var rawHTML = $('.WorkingHours').html();
$('.WorkingHours').html(rawHTML.replace(/<br \/>/g, ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

using `.text()` instead of `.html()` to remove html tags

`.text()` only returns the inner text, instead of the inner html.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to escape the forward-slash in the expression, e.g.

```
$('.WorkingHours').text().replace(/<br \/>/g, " ");
```

Comment: `$('.WorkingHours').text()` won't contain any HTML, so no `<br />` tags either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the forward slash in the `<br />`:

```
$('.WorkingHours').text().replace(/<br \/>/g, " ");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uLYrH/1

Comment: how do i find out if it is the last br tag and replace it with "."??

Comment: Your fiddle works because you are working with a string, but `$('.WorkingHours').text()` won't contain any HTML.