# very tricky html characters as text

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

```
<span class="WorkingHours">
   M,W,Th,F 7:30 AM - 4:00 PM &lt;br /&gt;Tu 7:30 AM - 6:00 PM &lt;br /&gt;
</span>
```

will be rendered as this

```
M,W,Th,F 7:30 AM - 4:00 PM <br />Tu 7:30 AM - 6:00 PM <br />
```

Now i need to replace the `&lt;br /&gt;` as an empty space before it is rendered??
I already asked a similar question, but i underestimated the trickiness of this..
I did this

```
$('.WorkingHours').text().replace(/<br \/>/g, " ");
```

didn't work..can someone help me out of this?

Shouldn't this work?

```
$('.WorkingHours').text().replace(/&lt;br \&gt;/g, " ");
```

Comment: You need to escape the < and > characters. try this `replace(/\<br \/\>/g, " ");`

Comment: If you use `.text()` instead of `.html()` and the code that uses the regular expression [from my answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704362/remove-all-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string-with-something-else-javascript), it will just work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/K9jVH/. Instead of creating a new question, you should have clarified your original one. That said, you should fix the HTML generation in the first place.

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry about that! will do that in the future

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you so much, it worked great! and sorry about the repost! Will keep that in mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
$('.WorkingHours').text(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/g, " "); 
});
```

​
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/K9jVH/)

In this case `.html()` would return the HTML entities (`&lt;`) whereas `.text()` returns the decoded characters (i.e. `<`). Given that,

```
$('.WorkingHours').text().replace(/<br \/>/g, " ")
```

actually [**works as well**](http://jsfiddle.net/K9jVH/1/) but you still have to assign the result back to the element.

[See also my previous answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9704416/218196)

---

Regarding replacing the last `<br />` with a different character: It might be possible with regular expressions, but in that case, I would just parse the text as HTML and perform the same operation as I showed [in my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9704416/218196):

```
var $content = $('<div />').html($('.WorkingHours').text());
$content 
 .find('br').last().replaceWith('.')
 .end().replaceWith(' ');

$('.WorkingHours').html($content.html());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/K9jVH/2/)

Comment: sir,is there a way to replace the last <br /> by '.'?? like using lastindexOF

Answer (score 0):

you have to escape the HTML characters to complete the pattern...

`replace(/\<br \/\>/g, " ");`

Answer (score 0):

If you have html entities in markup try replacing those instead

```
   replace('&lt;br \/&gt;', ' ')
```

Looks like you were missing a "/"