# Removing a replacing character using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a variable I have a string value Agriculture & Development. I want to remove Whitespaces and character '&' from the string Agriculture & Development so that it looks like Agriculture_Development using jquery or javascript.

Comment: So far so good. Apparently you don't have a question here, so just go ahead and do it.

Comment: Please Check this below link First google it before ask question


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145988/string-replace-in-jquery

Answer (score 4):

No need for jquery here, plain js will do:

```
var nwstr = 'Agriculture & Development'
                .replace(/\s+/g,'')
                .replace(/\&/,'_');
//=> Agriculture_Development
```

Now [go and figure](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/string4.shtml) things out yourself

Comment: Or `'Agriculture & Development'.replace(/[\s&]+/g,'_')` to simply replace all groups of space and/or `&` with a single `_`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "Agriculture & Development"; 
// replace all the white space and the &
str.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(/\&/,'_');
```