# How to show/add/modify text in a string with jquery

Tags: jquery, string, text

I have a title and a unorder list

```
<h2> here is some interesting links </h2>
 <ul>
  <li>link 1</li>
  <li>link 2</li>
  <li>link 3</li>
 </ul>
```

what I like is to add a [+] at the end of the  tag, and hide the following

  then on click on h2, show it.... BUT i need to mak e the [+] become a [-]

what is the best way to change that ?

it will look like :

**closed** : title [+]

**open** : title [-]

-link1

-link2

-link3

Comment: Where i am, the |+] is add in the shortcode, i like to take the h2 and remove the last 3 caracter and append [-] and vice-versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming no changes to your current HTML, and all modifications through jQuery:

```
$('h2').html(
    function(i,h) {
        return h + '<span>[+]</span>';
    }).on('click', 'span', function(){
        var that = $(this);
        that.closest('h2').next('ul').toggle();
        that.text(
            function(){
                return that.text().indexOf('+') !== -1 ? '[-]' : '[+]';
            });
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eQhVF/).

---

**Edited** to explain this part of the above code:

```
 return that.text().indexOf('+') !== -1 ? '[-]' : '[+]';
```

This is a ternary operator, it evaluates a condition (`return that.text().indexOf('+') !== -1`) for being true, or false. Following the `?` is the 'if-true' response, and following the `:` is the 'if-false' response.

So, the condition assesses whether or not the `+` character is found within the string returned from the `text()` of the current element. We're comparing the result to `-1` because `indexOf()` returns the index of the found substring. Because the substring can be found at `0` (the beginning of the string), `indexOf()` returns `-1` when the string is not found. Therefore if the `+` is found (so the returned result will *not* be equal to `-1`) within the text of the `span` element the text is changed to `[-]`, whereas if the `+` *is* found the text will be changed to `[-]`.

The `return` statement simply returns the changed-text to the `text()` method.

---

**Updated** to amend the `text()` method's function, and take advantage of the fact that the text of the element is available as the second parameter in the function:

```
$('h2').html(
    function(i,h) {
        return h + '<span>[+]</span>';
    }).on('click', 'span', function(){
        var that = $(this);
        that.closest('h2').next('ul').toggle();
        that.text(
            function(i,t){
                return t.indexOf('+') !== -1 ? '[-]' : '[+]';
            });
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eQhVF/1/).

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [JavaScript ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: I like the progressive enhancement nature of this solution.

Comment: @menardmam: really? Can I help with an explanation?

Comment: this is wizardry ? : return that.text().indexOf('+') !== -1 ? '[-]' : '[+]';

Answer (score 2):

Here is my fast improvisation. It should work.

*HTML:*

```
<h2>
    here is some interesting links
    <span class="toggle" data-target="list1">-</span>
</h2>
<ul id="list1">
    <li>link 1</li>
    <li>link 2</li>
    <li>link 3</li>
</ul>
```

*jQuery:*

```
$(".toggle").on("click", function() {
    var target = $(this).text(function(i, val) {
        return val == "+" ? "-" : "+";
    }).data("target");
    $("#" + target).toggle();
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/L3jep/

Comment: can you explain ot point to a page that explain that markup :         return val == "+" ? "-" : "+";

Comment: This is a short if clause: `if (val == "+") { return "-"; } else { return "+"; }`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Markup like this

```
<h2> here is some interesting links </h2>
<a  class="aExpand" href="#">+</a>
 <ul class="sub" style="display:none;">
  <li>link 1</li>
  <li>link 2</li>
  <li>link 3</li>
 </ul>
```

This script will do it

```
$(function(){
     $(".aExpand").click(function(e){
       var item=$(this);  
        if(item.next("ul").is(":visible"))
        {         
          item.text("+").next("ul").hide();

        }
        else
        {           
            item.text("-").next("ul").show();
        }

    });    
});
```

working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/BqKn5/8/

Answer (score 0):

my final code base on your help and from here : [How do I do string replace in JavaScript to convert ‘9.61’ to ‘9:61’?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145988/string-replace-in-jquery)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $('.bulletlisttohide').hide();

    $(".plus").click( function () {
        $(this).next('.bulletlisttohide').slideToggle(500, function (){
            if ($(this).is(":visible")) { $(this).prev('.plus').html(function(i, val) { return val.replace('[+]', '[-]'); }); }
            else { $(this).prev('.plus').html(function(i, val) { return val.replace('[-]', '[+]'); }); }
        });

        return false;
    });
})
</script>
```