# How do I replace “<br /><br />” with “<br />” in HTML using JavaScript and jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have validation summary that sometimes has multiple `br` tags at the end like below:

```
<div id="ValidationSummary1" class="alert alert-error">
    Last 4-digits of Social Security number does not match 
    the Member record on file for the Member ID number you 
    have entered.<br />
    Date of Birth does not match the Member record on file for the Member ID 
    number you have entered.<br /><br />
</div>
```

I'm trying to find anytime there are two `br` tags back to back and replace it with one like below:

```
$('#ValidationSummary1').replace('<br /><br />', '<br />');
```

I understand there isn't a `replace()` function.  What would be the alternative to something simple like this?

Comment: Possible repeat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145988/string-replace-in-jquery

Comment: try this: `$('#ValidationSummary1').replace('<br /><br />', '<br />');`

Comment: @Asdfg - jQuery itself doesn't have a .replace() function, which is why I posted the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `.html()` to get and set the content passing it through the standard JS `replace()`.

```
var div = $('#ValidationSummary1');
div.html(div.html().replace('<br /><br />', '<br />'));
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript itself *does* have a `replace` function, and given that jQuery is a framework built *upon* JavaScript, you do have that method available. So, this means you'll have to do a get-manipulate-set process instead of perhaps some nice jQuery method chaining to do it in place.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var $val= $('#ValidationSummary1');
 $val.html($val.html().replace(/[<br>]+$/, '<br/>');
```

whatever the number of 
 they will be replaced by one 
 (better html)

Answer (score 0):

In your case (need to remove html tags) the best solution is to use `.text()` instead of `.html()`. The difference is that `.html()` keeps html tags, and `.text()` keeps only text (removes any html).

For example:

```
var value1 = $('.some_div').html(); //returns text content with HTML tags
var value2 = $('.some_div').text(); //returns only text content
```