# Find text and replace other text

Tags: jquery, html, replace

I could help, I need a code in jQuery to do the following:

A code each time it finds "**Texto 0**" in any part of the body. When is "**Texto 0**"  replace style1 by style2  (or remove style1 and add style2)

My code is this. The "..." represent other codes in between.

```
<div span="menu> <span> Texto 0 </ span> </ div>
....
....
...
<span class="style1"> Hello </ span>
```

Comment: maybe that's what you're looking for?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145988/string-replace-in-jquery

Answer (score 1):

```
$('span:contains("Texto 0")').each(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('style1'))
        $(this).removeClass('style1').addClass('style2');
});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kf7pZ/1/).

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('span').each(function(index) {
     if($(this).val().indexOf("Text 0") !== -1) {
       $(this).removeClass('style1')
       $(this).addClass('style2')
     }
   })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but I think I did not explain well. Esque I need this code to a forum.

I need code in jQuery using 1.7.2. The "...." other codes represent images, paragraphs, tables, etc..

[JSFIDDLE][1]

When the "Texto 0"  style1 by style2 change. If you are not the "Texto 0", the default style is style1. I mean, if it is not "Texto 0", the function would not apply


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/Kf7pZ/2/