# Remove all backslashes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, slash

How to remove all backslash in a JavaScript string ?

```
var str = "one thing\\\'s for certain: power blackouts and surges can damage your equipment.";
```

I want output like

```
one thing's for certain: power blackouts and surges can damage your equipment.
```

Update:

I am scrapping data from page with help of JavaScript & displaying on fancy-box popup.

please help me on this

Comment: Just for the sake of future generations: those are **backslash** characters. A slash looks like: `/`

Comment: Does that output come from a database? If so what language are you using there? If so it might be better to remove those backslashes server side

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use a simple regex to solve it

```
str = str.replace(/\\/g, '')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cW62s/)

Comment: it gives output like

one thing\\'s for certain: power blackouts and surges can damage your equipment.

just removed 1 slash form 3

Comment: @user2046091: Your example has only one backslash in the string (and two only for escaping in the literal, of whom one is unnecessary)?

Comment: @j08691 it is because there is only one instance of `\ ` in the page, if there are multiple instances then `g` flag is required

Comment: @ArunPJohny - doesn't \\ escape the \, meaning it's only looking for a single \?

Comment: As pointed out by @Pointy those are backslashes: to remove **slashes**  instead it should be `str = str.replace(/\//g,'')`

Answer (score 14):

This is the answer according to the title as the title is "**Remove all slashes in Javascript**" *not backslashes*. So here is the code to remove all the slashes from a string in JavaScript.

```
str = '/mobiles-phones/.png';
str.replace(/\//g, "")//output would be "mobiles-phones.png";
```

Comment: ..except those aren't backslashes ;)

Comment: The title is changed now. Good

Answer (score 3):

Regexs are great `str.replace(/\\/g,'')`

Answer (score -3):

[How do I do string replace in JavaScript to convert ‘9.61’ to ‘9:61’?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145988/string-replace-in-jquery)

```
var str = "one thing\\\'s for certain: power blackouts and surges can damage your equipment.";

str.replace("\", "");
```

Comment: jQuery... seriously? There should be no mentions of jQuery anywhere near this question! Plus, you have a syntax error.

Comment: Did you try that? And OP did not ask for jQuery.